# GitLab mirroring feature doesn't work when pulling from a remote repo

Tags: git, gitlab

I cloned my repo into `GitLab` (SaaS - Bronze plan) from `bitbucket` over `HTTPS`, which was successful.
Then I tried to setup a mirror (pull) to pull into Gitlab, all changes made to bitbucket. I entered the right details ,ie, the URL of the repo and the password but the mirroring fails and throws the following error -

[image]

[image]

HELP!!!

Answer (score 2):

We've opened [gitlab-ce#61624](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/61624); should be addressed with [this MR](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/28223).

Comment: I see that the issue has been closed. But I still see the same error. 
Does this mean that PROD has not been updated with the latest changes?

Comment: @ArchitArora That's correct. This is scheduled for 11.11 release (22 May), though it may hit GitLab.com sooner in a release candidate. It's advised that you follow along with and comment in the issue should problems persist, as that provides direct engagement with engineers who are working on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There have been similar issue with remote repo mirroring before ([gitlab-ee/issues 2000](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/2000), on the push side)

In your case:

- check your remote repo default branch
- check your associated password (there could be a special character used)
- check if your BitBucket account has [2FA activated](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/two-step-verification-777023203.html) (in which case the password should be a PAT, Personal Access Token)

Comment: 1. Default branch is master 2. No special character in my password 3. 2FA not activated.

Also, I tried to do the same thing on enterprise hosted GitLab and the mirroring worked. I think the issue is with the SaaS offering

Comment: @ArchitArora Certainly: I don't know what version of GitLab it runs (presumably the latest?), but this should then be reported as a bug on their issue tracker.